# Difficulty receiving JSON from GET request using NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, afnetworking-2, nsurlsession

I'm having a hard time trying to receive JSON form a `NSURLConnection` request. Can anybody offer any advice? I can't understand why the JSON does not appear

EDIT: When I append the endpoint /books to the end of the url string I get this JSON response: " json   NSDictionary *  0 key/value pairs. " Does this mean that there is nothing in the server?

```
-(void)makeLibraryRequests
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://prolific-interview.herokuapp.com/54bexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaa56"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; //;]cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
//    This is actually how jQuery works. If you don't tell it what to do with the result, it uses the Content-type to detect what to do with it.
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    //parse data here!!

    NSError *jsonError;
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

    if (json) {
        //NSArray *allBooks = [json objectForKey:@"books"];

        //create your MutableArray here

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"error occured %@", jsonError);

        NSString *serverResponse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"\n\nError:\n%@\n\nServer Response:\n%@\n\nCrash:", jsonError.description, serverResponse);
        //[NSException raise:@"Invalid Data" format:@"Unable to process web server response."];
    }

}];

}
```

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: Your link is not a JSON link. It's website so its content is HTML. What do you want to parse?

Comment: @VietHung I am trying to GET books/ from the JSON. Sorry I should have specified. Do you think it is possible to GET JSON from an HTML link?

Comment: @hsavit1: HTML is a XML format. It can not be JSON format :D. if you want to learn how to request/receive data with `NSURLConnection`, see AFNetworking

Answer (score 1):

As YiPing pointed out, you must provide the `books` end point. But you won't have anything there until you first post a book.

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"author": @"Diego Torres Milano",
                         @"categories" : @"android,testing",
                         @"title": @"Android Application Testing Guide",
                         @"publisher": @"Packt Publishing",
                         @"lastCheckedOutBy": @"Joe"};

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://prolific-interview.herokuapp.com/54bexxxxxxxxxxxxxaa56/books/"];  // your id removed for security's sake ... put it back in
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSError *encodeError;
NSData *body = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&encodeError];
NSAssert(body, @"JSON encode failed: %@", encodeError);
request.HTTPBody = body;
```

So, first `POST` a book using a request like the above, then your original `GET` (assuming you add the end point) will now return a result.

Answer (score 0):

Add some endpoints to your URL

try this:

http://prolific-interview.herokuapp.com/54bexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxaa56/books/

Comment: My mistake. I mean making making request using this url  [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://prolific-interview.herokuapp.com/54be71eb46c2c2000866aa56"]

Comment: @hsavit1 No, the url in your question is missing that end point, `books`.

Comment: @Rob thanks for your response. When I append the endpoint /books to the end of the url string I get this JSON response:     "  json NSDictionary * 0 key/value pairs.  " Does this mean that there is nothing in the server?

Comment: I was just looking at it and got an empty response with that endpoint. Have you posted any books yet?

Comment: For the record, I don't know why this answer was down-voted, as it really gets to the first critical problem in the request, IMHO, the failure to supply an end point to the request.